# Arc given two points and their start / end tangents

Tags: geometry

Given two points ($p_0$ and $p_1$) and their (start/end) tangents ($t_0$ and $t_1$), how can I find the arc that joins them?

Thanks!

[image: Representation of the problem]

Comment: You cannot. In the sense that there is no unique arc that joins them.

Comment: There can be infinitely many arcs. So I'm not clear as to what you are asking

Comment: Is the arc constrained to be only a circular arc? If so, there might even be 0 arcs that are possible.

Comment: I'm sorry but why are there infinite arcs that joins the two points(given the two tangents?)
Shouldn't there be only one arc?
http://i.imgur.com/iOE4Qrh.png

Comment: @Element118 yes, it is only an Arc of a Cirlce, not an Elliptical Arc.

Comment: A circle is uniquely determined by the 2 points and 1 tangent, so your system is overdetermined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a circular arc, all you need to do is to draw the two lines perpendicular to each tangent at their points $P_0$ and $P_1$: the point of intersection of these lines is the center $C$ of the circle. Unfortunately that works only if the distance of $C$ from $P_0$ and $P_1$ is the same, but in general this is not guaranteed to be true and no fitting circular arc exists.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly.
In case the two lines are parallel, I just calculated the midpoint of the segment that joins them without using the perpendicular lines.